# Extra bracket in my JSON object created from a string Xamarin Android

Tags: json, xamarin.android

I create a JSONObject from a string as following:

```
string mystring="{\"number\":  1, \"Type \": \"phone\",  \"X \": 2, \"Y \":3}";
JSONObject myjsonobject= new JSONObject(mystring);
```

And I find in the debugging that myjsonobject has an extra bracket as you can see here:

```
{{"number ":1,"Type ":"phone","X ":2,"Y ":3}}
```

So I cannot get any value of my jsonobject. How can I fix that issue please?